# Is there a way to block the recreation of the "bug" tag on the main site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags, blacklist

I've been editing out the [bug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug) tag from threads on the main site because I've noticed that there were just a few questions tagged with it and that it doesn't improve the post in any way that can't be achieved with more specific tags. Also, the user almost always doesn't have enough skills and tools to be certain that they have really found a bug, and not just an error caused by themselves or a third-party element. Moreover, if the person is completely sure and has proof that they are dealing with a bug, they should be reporting it to the developers of the subject matter instead of posting it to Super User.

What do you think about it? Is there a way to prevent users from using this tag again?

Comment: Don't forget about [tag:bugs] as well.

Comment: I wouldn't manually edit out the tag. It causes a lot of posts to be unnecessarily bumped. Make an official `retag-request` for having the tag removed from all posts.

Comment: @slhck I did other changes to the posts besides removing the tag, and this is supposed to the an official request. I just hadn't added the retag-request tag to it, but kinokijuf has now did it.

Comment: @screener I see, well it's always good to fix other stuff as you go, and I remember you doing it, so that's fine :) I just wouldn't do it for more than 10 posts or so.

Comment: @slhck Yeah, thanks for the reminder. I stopped doing it after I saw your first comment.

Comment: In order to remove and prevent the recreation of a bad tag, it has to be blacklisted by a developer. I think this would be a reasonable tag to do so with.

Answer (score 3):

I just removed this tag from the last 5 questions that had it. [bug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug) is now blacklisted.

Comment: How about [bugs](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugs), as *soandos* commented above?

Comment: @Karan I don't think it's explicitly blacklisted, but there are 0 questions in it, so it doesn't seem like a concern. If it becomes overused, let me know.

Comment: Anna, there are actually 0 questions for it because I drew attention to it [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6301/remove-bugs-tag-on-main-site) before I found this post, and Sathya took care of it. Perhaps it can be blacklisted now to prevent reuse?

Comment: @Karan Both [bug] and [bugs] should be blacklisted now.