# Remove bugs tag on Main site

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Is there any point keeping [bugs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugs) on the main site around?

Related: [Is there a way to block the recreation of the "bug" tag on the main site?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4010/is-there-a-way-to-block-the-recreation-of-the-bug-tag-on-the-main-site) (where *soandos* even [commented](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4010/is-there-a-way-to-block-the-recreation-of-the-bug-tag-on-the-main-site#comment9891_4010) about and drew attention to it, but to no avail apparently. At least [bug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug) was blacklisted successfully though.)

Comment: I was initially really confused because I thought you were suggesting to remove the [meta-tag:bug] tag from meta. And was thinking "ummm that's one of the _build in meta tags_", until I realized I just fail at reading comprehension.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I rolled back your [edit](http://meta.superuser.com/revisions/6301/2). Seems you got confused just like nhinkle did. I'm *not* talking about removing the "bugs" tag from meta.su; I'm advocating removal of the "bugs" tag from the main site because it seems to be a meta tag to me.

Comment: You might mention that in the question and remove the references to "meta tag" then, lest someone _else_ get confused. :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Why remove it? Have you seen just [how many times](http://meta.superuser.com/search?q=meta+tag) the "meta tag" phrase has been used? A "meta tag" is a "meta tag", not a "tag (used) on meta"!

Comment: OK, I get it now.

Comment: I was about to write the same thing as @nhinkle & Michael - for the rest it's not very clear and first thing that comes to my mind is - "hmm, I know bug is a tag used on meta, why would be want to remove it?"

Comment: @Sathya: Please re-word if you can make it easier to understand; was in a bit of a hurry and was terse as a result thinking it would be understood (esp. since the link pointed to the tag on the main site and not on meta). Anyway, now 2 mods have understood what I meant, and it's really you guys who would implement this in any case.

Comment: @Karan it's not really up to us to implement since we can't do mass tag removals (only mass tag replacements) - neither can we do blacklists - we're as powerful as Community members when it comes to tag removal & must be done manually. We can, however, ask the Dev/Comm team to do mass burninates but that's quite rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no more questions with tag [bugs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugs)

Comment: That's great, and I've requested over on the other thread to have it blacklisted as well.